# Why do so many solutions to $n+1\mid3^n+1$ satisfy $n\equiv27\pmod{72}$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Here are the first $40$ integers for which $\dfrac{3^n+1}{n+1}$ is an integer. I've denoted their residue mod $72$ by color and a symbol.
$$\begin{array}{r}\dagger\,\color{violet}0,&\bullet\,\color{brown}1,&*\,\color{red}3,&27,&531,\\
1\,035,&4\,635,&6\,363,&11\,475,&19\,683,\\
4\,131,&80\,955,&*\,\color{red}{266\,475},&280\,755,&307\,395,\\
356\,643,&\circ\,\color{blue}{490\,371},&544\,347,&557\,955,&565\,515,\\
572\,715,&808\,227,&1\,256\,355,&1\,695\,483,&1\,959\,075,\\
1\,995\,075,&2\,771\,595,&2\,837\,835,&3\,004\,155,&3\,208\,491,\\
*\,\color{red}{3\,337\,635},&3\,886\,443,&4\,670\,955,&5\,619\,411,&6\,434\,595,\\
\bullet\,\color{brown}{6\,942\,817},&*\,\color{red}{7\,631\,715},&*\,\color{red}{9\,274\,755},&9\,436\,923,&9\,586\,107,\end{array}$$
$\dagger\,\color{violet}{\rm Violet}$ means $0$ mod $72$, $\circ\,\color{blue}{\rm blue}$ means $51$ mod $72$, $\bullet\,\color{brown}{\rm brown}$ means $1$ mod $72$, $*\,\color{red}{\rm red}$ means $3$ mod $72$. All the rest, ${\rm black}$, are $27$ mod $72$.

Why are so many solutions ($31$ of the first $40$) equivalent to $27$ mod $72$? It can't be a coincidence that (beyond $n=3$) the counterexamples are so few and take so long to show up.

Some other observations. Of the first $40$ solutions:

- $32$ of them are multiples of $9$.
- $37$ of them are $3$ mod $8$.
- $38$ of them are multiples of $3$.

I was honestly ready to conjecture that (other than $1$) all solutions were multiples of $3$, until $6\,942\,817$ showed up. Why is the first non-multiple of $3$ so large?? That same number is also the first one after $1$ that's not $3$ mod $8$. What's going on here?

---

Python code:

```
for n in range(10_000_000):
  if (pow(3,n,n+1)==n):
    print(n)
```

---

EDIT: Here's a graph of "What percentage of the first $x$ nonzero values are $27$ mod $72$?" as $x$ ranges from $1$ to $213$:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/o1agwn8feo
(Thanks to Zubin Mukerjee for the list of the first 213 nonzero values)

---

The sequence is now on OEIS. https://oeis.org/A370578

Comment: A more computer-friendly list of the first 40 solutions: `0, 1, 3, 27, 531, 1035, 4635, 6363, 11475, 19683, 40131, 80955, 266475, 280755, 307395, 356643, 490371, 544347, 557955, 565515, 572715, 808227, 1256355, 1695483, 1959075, 1995075, 2771595, 2837835, 3004155, 3208491, 3337635, 3886443, 4670955, 5619411, 6434595, 6942817, 7631715, 9274755, 9436923, 9586107`

Comment: This list continues forever because $3^{3^k}$ is a solution for all $k\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: I think there might be a typo in your title

Comment: Thanks! Fixed. (The title was correct; the text was not. @H.sapiensrex)

Comment: I checked some more solutions (the first $80$ or so) using Python. Except for the first $0$, it seems the only residues mod $72$ that appear are $1$, $3$, $27$, and $51$. It might be interesting to see a histogram.

Comment: Note that:

$$3^n \operatorname{mod} 72 = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } n = 0 \\
3 & \text{if } n = 1 \\
9 & \text{if } n \ge 2 \text { is even}\\
27 & \text{if } n \ge 3 \text { is odd}\\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Surprisingly, your sequence isn't on oeis.org yet.

Comment: @Dan I'm applying for an OEIS account as we speak, so that I can put this up there.

Comment: All $84$ terms below $10^8$ plotted against their values mod $72$: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwf1x.png

Comment: By brute-forcing the equivalent equation $\exists k\in\mathbb{Z} : k(n+1) = 3^n+1 \pmod{m}$ for $2 \le m \le 16$, I've found the result $n \ne m - 1 \pmod{3, 8, 10, 11, 13, 16}$.  Combining the mod 3 and 8 results gives $n \in \{ 0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 12, 13, 16, 18, 19, 21, 22, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 33, 34, 36, 37, 40, 42, 43, 45, 46, 48, 49, 51, 52, 54, 57, 58, 60, 61, 64, 66, 67, 69, 70 \} \pmod{72}$, which contains $27$, but doesn't explain why it's over-represented in actual solutions.

Comment: @Dan It's up now! https://oeis.org/A370578

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer shows that, apart from $n = 0$, all solutions of $n$ are odd. Also, if $3 \mid n$, then $n \equiv 3 \pmod{24}$, so $n$ is congruent to one of $3$, $27$ or $51$ mod $72$, as your results show. OTOH, if $3 \nmid n$, then $n \equiv 1 \pmod{12}$.

This solution also gives heuristic explanations about why almost all $n$ are divisible by $3$, with most being divisible by $9$, i.e., with $n \equiv 27\pmod{72}$.

The following only considers $n \gt 0$. Also, note that

$$3^n \equiv -1 \pmod{n + 1} \;\;\;\to\;\;\; 3^{2n} \equiv 1 \pmod{n + 1} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

---

Assume an integer solution $n$ to \eqref{eq1A} is even. Using the [$p$-adic valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_valuation) function, this means

$$\nu_2(n) = i \;\;\;\to\;\;\; n = 2^{i}j, \;\; i\ge 1, \;\; 2\nmid j \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Since $n + 1$ is odd and $\gt 1$, it's a product of one or more odd prime factors. Using the [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order), for any one of these prime factors $p$, plus also using \eqref{eq1A} and \eqref{eq2A}, we get

$$\operatorname{ord}_p(3) = m \;\;\to\;\; m \nmid 2^{i}j, \; m \mid 2^{i+1}j \;\;\to\;\; m = 2^{i+1}k, \; k \mid j \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

The conclusion that $2^{i+1}\mid m$ comes from, if it did not, then $m \mid n$ which is not allowed since that would mean $1 \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$.

From [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) and that $\varphi(p) = p - 1$, we then also have

$$m \mid p - 1 \;\;\;\to\;\;\; p \equiv 1 \pmod{2^{i+1}} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Since \eqref{eq4A} is true for *every* prime factor $p$ of $n + 1$, this means the product of all of the prime factors of $n + 1$, including multiple ones, gives that

$$n + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod{2^{i+1}} \;\;\to\;\; n \equiv 0 \pmod{2^{i+1}} \;\;\to\;\; 2^{i+1} \mid n \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

However, this contradicts \eqref{eq2A}, thus proving there are no such even solutions of $n$.

---

For odd $n$, with every odd prime factor $p$ of $n + 1$, the LHS of \eqref{eq1A} shows that $3$ and $-1$ are either both quadratic residues or both quadratic nonresidues mod $p$. To see this, note each prime has a [primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) $g$, so any congruence expressed in terms of powers of $g$ requires the difference of the exponents to be divisible by $p - 1$, which is even, so the exponents must have the same parity.

The table in the [Law of quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Law_of_quadratic_reciprocity) section of Wikipedia's "Quadratic residue" article shows $3$ is a quadratic residue iff $p \equiv 1, 11 \pmod{12}$, while $-1$ is a quadratic residue iff $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. Combining these shows $3$ and $-1$ are both quadratic residues iff $p \equiv 1 \pmod{12}$, while they are both quadratic nonresidues (since $p \neq 3$) iff $p \equiv 7 \pmod{12}$. These together give that

$$p \equiv 1 \pmod{6} \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Since $p$ is *any* odd prime which divides $n + 1$, this means the product of all of them is congruent to $1$ mod $6$.

Due to $3^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$, we have $3^n + 1 \equiv 4 \pmod{8}$, so $n + 1$ can have only $1$ or $2$ factors of $2$. For the latter case,

$$n + 1 \equiv 4 \pmod{6} \;\;\;\to\;\;\; n \equiv 3 \pmod{6} \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

Also $n + 1 \equiv 4 \pmod{8} \;\to\; n \equiv 3 \pmod{8}$ so, since $\operatorname{lcm}(6, 8) = 24$, this combined with \eqref{eq7A} gives

$$n \equiv 3 \pmod{24} \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

As stated initially, this gives that $3 \mid n$ and $n \equiv 3, 27, 51 \pmod{72}$.

If $n + 1$ has just $1$ factor of $2$ instead, we then get

$$n + 1 \equiv 2 \pmod{6} \;\;\;\to\;\;\; n \equiv 1 \pmod{6} \tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$

Since we also have $n + 1 \equiv 2 \pmod{4} \;\to\; n \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, we get altogether that

$$n \equiv 1 \pmod{12} \tag{10}\label{eq10A}$$

---

Regarding why most $n$ are divisible by $3$, note \eqref{eq6A} shows that $p - 1$ always has at least one factor of $3$. If $3 \nmid n$, then \eqref{eq2A} and \eqref{eq3A} show that $3 \nmid m$ for *every* odd prime factor of $n + 1$, with this excluding many possible prime factors (especially the smaller ones) possibly being used. As for why $n \equiv 27 \pmod{72}$ is so relatively common, note it's the only congruence where $9 \mid n$. Many prime factors have $9 \mid m$, so having even one such prime factor in $n + 1$ would require that $9 \mid n$. Finally, the above only specifies the minimum # of factors of $3$, so $n + 1$ may have more than that, e.g., for $n = 3$ and $n = 27$.

Values of $n$ where $3 \nmid n$ are given by \eqref{eq10A}, so $n \equiv 1, 13, 25, 37, 49, 61 \pmod{72}$. As for why we only have $n \equiv 1 \pmod{72}$ or $n \equiv 25 \pmod{72}$ so far, and not also any other values, note you have only found $2$ values so far where $n \equiv 1 \pmod{72}$, and [Zubin Mukerjee's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4867910/why-do-so-many-solutions-to-n1-mid3n1-satisfy-n-equiv27-pmod72#comment10379318_4868045) states "...  the 98th solution, $193264225 \equiv 25 \pmod{72}$". Thus, unless there's some specific reason why any of the other possible congruences should be excluded, I suspect examples of each of them will be found when large enough values of $n$ are checked.

Comment: Apologies. You are right - of course $n$ can't be $3 \pmod{72}$ and not divisible by $3$. By the way, the last sentence in your answer is supported by the 98th solution, $193264225 \equiv 25 \pmod{72}$. Of the $214$ solutions under 2 billion, $169$ are $27 \pmod{72}$. No residues of $13$, $37$, $49$, or $61$ are found, but you are probably correct that these will eventually appear.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee No worries. Thanks for the additional information. I've updated my answer to include your result that $193264225 \equiv 25 \pmod{72}$ is a solution. Also, I would be interested to know about any other pertinent information you determine about this problem.

Comment: Do you have any insight on how common $27$ mod $72$ should be, as the length of the list goes to infinity? (Here's a graph of the empirical data so far: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/o1agwn8feo)

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger I don't have any particular insight regarding how relatively common the $27$ mod $72$ solutions should be for any particular upper bound being checked as it goes to infinity. Your graph looks interesting, especially how it fluctuates quite a bit between about $10$ and $70$, before then basically stabilizing. Although it appears to be steady at about $0.8$, I expect that it will gradually increase, with it becoming arbitrarily close to $1.0$, as the values become very large. This is because, as I explained in my answer, if $n+1$ has *any* prime factor $p$ where its ...

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger (cont.) multiplicative order $m$ is such that $9\mid m$, then $9\mid n$ so $n\equiv 27\pmod{72}$. Since I'm quite certain that the number of primes where such a condition is applicable is infinite, the chances of at least one such prime being a factor of $n+1$ will keep growing as $n$ increases. Nonetheless, this growth rate will likely be *very* minimal. Thus, $n$ may potentially need to become more than the order of perhaps a googol, or even a [googolplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googolplex), before the ratio becomes quite close to $1.0$.

Comment: The sequence is now on OEIS. https://oeis.org/A370578